# Why there are verilog verification files not in the form of module?

Tags: verilog, verification

Why are there Verilog verification files not in the form of a `module`?
The files I see start with just `initial begin`, and some file names use the `.inc` extension.

Comment: Generally in verilog ".inc" extension files are not used and a verilog testbench file is used for verification of a verilog file which should also be ending with extension ".v" or the file with inital begin(ie. stimulus ) should be included using `include directive to the testbench file, If you are new to verilog, suggestion is to go through the link mentioned http://www.testbench.in/TB_00_INDEX.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to include files of arbitrary content into Verilog modules.  This is done using the `` `include `` compiler directive, as described in IEEE Std 1800-2012, section "22.4 *`include*":

> The file inclusion (include) compiler directive is used to insert the
>   entire contents of a source file in another file during compilation.
>   The result is as though the contents of the included source file
>   appear in place of the `include compiler directive.

It can be useful for sharing common code between different modules: parameters, define macros, tasks, functions, etc.

In general, the `.inc` file extension is not special.  It may be a convention used by certain simulation tools.